# Question related to Potential Energy - Mass Spring System

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, spring

The P.E stored by a mass spring system at an extension of 2cm is 10J. The P.E stored by the same system at an extension of 4cm will be?
Someone please provide an extensive answer if possible.

Comment: -1 . No research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple,

PE/pe = (dX/dx)^2 so that PE = pe (4/2)^2 = 40 J.

> *PE varies with the square of the deformation dX.*

It can also be explained in this way,

*Elastic potential energy is proportional to the square of the stretched length. Multiplying the length by 2 will thereby multiply the PE by 2^2 or 4.*

10 J * 4 = 40 J

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider your spring is a linear spring, that is it creates a force $F = kx$, where $k$ is the spring constant of the spring and $x$ its extension. Then, you can find that $$F = \frac{\textrm{d} }{\textrm{d}x}\frac{1}{2} kx^2$$

So the potential energy associated with the spring is, imposing that $E_p(x=0) = 0$, $$E_p = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

You know the potential energy $E_{p,0}$ corresponding to a given $x_0$, so for every $x$,

$$E_p = \frac{1}{2}kx_0^2 \times (\frac{x}{x_0})^2 = E_{p,0}(\frac{x}{x_0})^2$$

In your case, $x_0 = 2$ cm, $E_{p,0} = 10$ J, $x = 4$ cm, so $E_p = 40$ J.